# How to use ag-grid in a Nuxt app

Tags: vuejs2, ag-grid, nuxt.js

I'm building a Nuxt application and I'm trying to render an ag-grid in one of my pages

I created a plugin called `ag-grid.js`:

```
import * as agGridEnterpise from 'ag-grid-enterprise/main'

agGridEnterpise.LicenseManager.setLicenseKey([MY_LICENSE_KEY])
```

On `nuxt.config.js` i have registered the plugin:

```
plugins: [
    //...
    {
      src: '~/plugins/ag-grid.js',
      ssr: false
    }
],
```

And in my page component i have:

```
<template>
    <ag-grid-vue ref="table" class="ag-theme-material" 
 :pinnedTopRowData="pinnedRow ? [pinnedRow] : []" :gridOptions="gridOptions" 
 :columnDefs="columnDefs" :rowData="tableData" v-show="!loadingGridData" 
 :cellValueChanged="onCellValueChanged">
    </ag-grid-vue>
</template>
<script>
import { AgGridVue } from 'ag-grid-vue'
export default {
  // ....
  components: {
    'ag-grid-vue': AgGridVue
    // ....
  }
}
</script>
```

But when I'm rendering the page i get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at Environment.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/environment.js.Environment.getTheme (C:\xampp\htdocs\ate_crm_webapp\node_modules\ag-grid\dist\lib\environment.js:76)
    at GridOptionsWrapper.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/gridOptionsWrapper.js.GridOptionsWrapper.specialForNewMaterial (C:\xampp\htdocs\ate_crm_webapp\node_modules\ag-grid\dist\lib\gridOptionsWrapper.js:636)
    at GridOptionsWrapper.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/gridOptionsWrapper.js.GridOptionsWrapper.getHeaderHeight (C:\xampp\htdocs\ate_crm_webapp\node_modules\ag-grid\dist\lib\gridOptionsWrapper.js:352)
    at GridOptionsWrapper.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/gridOptionsWrapper.js.GridOptionsWrapper.getGroupHeaderHeight (C:\xampp\htdocs\ate_crm_webapp\node_modules\ag-grid\dist\lib\gridOptionsWrapper.js:368)
    at GridPanel.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/gridPanel/gridPanel.js.GridPanel.setBodyAndHeaderHeights (C:\xampp\htdocs\ate_crm_webapp\node_modules\ag-grid\dist\lib\gridPanel\gridPanel.js:1193)
    at GridPanel.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/gridPanel/gridPanel.js.GridPanel.init (C:\xampp\htdocs\ate_crm_webapp\node_modules\ag-grid\dist\lib\gridPanel\gridPanel.js:191)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\ate_crm_webapp\node_modules\ag-grid\dist\lib\context\context.js:215
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\ate_crm_webapp\node_modules\ag-grid\dist\lib\context\context.js:215
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)`

And i get a Vue warning:

```
[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

found in

---> <AgGridVue>
       //....
```

Any clue what's going on?

Comment: Hey, can you reproduce the problem in a sample repo? I can take a look. The error means that the grid failed to find the element with 'ag-theme-material' class set. Why this is so is hard to say, though.

Comment: Here's a repo with the example. I'm actually having a different error with 'MouseEvent' not found which is even more baffling.. https://github.com/bahatron/agGrid-Nuxt-sample.

Comment: The mouse event in SSR is known problem - https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2187. I am not a Vue expert, though - let me know how I can reproduce the problem you mentioned initially.

Comment: I would try first with " <ag-grid-vue ref="table" />", and see if you have errors. I have a guts feeling that there's some linking issues, not anything to do with the css theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ag-grid failed to find the css. That's why you need these lines to your nuxt.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  css: [
    '@/node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css',
    '@/node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.css'
  ],
build: ect...
```

To resolve the other answerers problems (like MouseEvent error) put this to the build:

```
build: {
  extend (config, context) {
    config.resolve.alias['vue'] = 'vue/dist/vue.common'
  }
}
```

Comment: This solves the issue! Thank you very much.

I'll update the github repo example so people can see it working!

Comment: It works on ag-grid-vue@^15.0.0 but not on ag-grid-vue@^16.0.0

I updated a repo showcasing an ag-grid table working on Nuxt (tagged) and then updating ag-grid to v16 without success
https://github.com/bahatron/agGrid-Nuxt-sample

Comment: I know this problem, thats why i also downgrade the version number back to the 15.0.0...
"MouseEvent undefined"
Issue about the problem: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2187

Comment: Anybody have this working on ag-grid 17?  I'm having this exact issue with `Nuxt: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`

Comment: @YeB: I also using now the ag-grid v17.0, but i don't have this problem. Maybe you need to uninstall the grid from your node_modules and after that install it again. I hope it's solves your problem.