# Nuxt and Ag Grid issue SyntaxError Missing stack frames

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid, nuxt.js

Trying to add ag-grid in the nuxt app.

I followed the steps from 
https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-getting-started/
and 
[How to use ag-grid in a Nuxt app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48870715/how-to-use-ag-grid-in-a-nuxt-app)

- Added the styles in nuxt.config.js
- Made a plugin and included in nuxt.config.js
- Created the component  AgGridDemo.vue
- Including component in page index.vue

**Note: Please do not try to run the snippets since I only used them to share the source I have.**

My nuxt.config.js file

```js
require('dotenv').config()
import pkg from './package'

export default {
  mode: 'universal',

  /*
   ** Headers of the page
   */
  head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }]
  },

  /*
   ** Customize the progress-bar color
   */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },

  /*
   ** Global CSS
   */
  css: [
    { src: '~assets/bulma-modifications.scss', lang: 'scss' },
    { src: 'font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss', lang: 'scss' },
    { src: '~/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css',  lang: 'css' },
    { src: '~/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-dark.css',  lang: 'css' }
  ],

  /*
   ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
   */
  plugins: [
    {
      src: '~/plugins/plugin-ag-grid.js',
      ssr: false
    },
    {
      src: '~plugins/plugin-vue-chartjs.js',
      ssr: false
    }
  ],

  /*
   ** Nuxt.js modules
   */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // Doc: https://buefy.github.io/#/documentation
    'nuxt-buefy',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv'
  ],
  /*
   ** Axios module configuration
   */
  axios: {
    // See https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#options
  },

  /*
   ** Build configuration
   */
  build: {
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    extend(config, ctx) {
      config.resolve.alias['vue'] = 'vue/dist/vue.common'
      // Run ESLint on save
      if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      }
      config.node = {
        fs: 'empty'
      }
    }
  },
  env: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'
  }
}
```

My Plugin plugin-ag-grid.js:

```js
import * as agGridEnterpise from 'ag-grid-enterprise/main'
require('dotenv').config()
agGridEnterpise.LicenseManager.setLicenseKey([process.env.AG_LICENSE_KEY])
```

My Component AgGridDemo.vue:

```js
<template>
  <ag-grid-vue
    style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    :columnDefs="columnDefs"
    :rowData="rowData"
  ></ag-grid-vue>
</template>
<script>
import { AgGridVue } from 'ag-grid-vue'

export default {
  name: 'AgGridDemo',
  data() {
    return {
      columnDefs: null,
      rowData: null
    }
  },
  components: {
    AgGridVue
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.columnDefs = [
      { headerName: 'Make', field: 'make' },
      { headerName: 'Model', field: 'model' },
      { headerName: 'Price', field: 'price' }
    ]

    this.rowData = [
      { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
      { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
      { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 }
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```

Finally My Page:

```js
<template>
  <section class="section">
    Welcome to test page
    <aggriddemo></aggriddemo>
  </section>
</template>
<script>

import AgGridDemo from '~/components/AgGridDemo'
export default {
  name: 'IndexPage',
  components: {
    AgGridDemo
  }
}
</script>
```

I am getting Error on the Screen but not on my console, console says Compiled successfully but on screen I get:

SyntaxError Missing

stack frames

[image]

Any Ideas on why is this happening and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying every solution given here (Thanks for posting), I managed to render the ag-grid on a nuxt project [using < no-ssr > tag](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-no-ssr/) and dynamic import (minute 7:40 is explained how to do it, if you are not familiar with codesplitting I deeply recommend to watch the whole video) [dynamic import video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2J9cTtlBXI).

How did I get there? Well, Since Andrew wrote that the problem may have something to do with ssr,[I switched my nuxt project into mode: 'spa'](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-mode/) and BOOM! ag-grid-vue showed up. Now the problem was, many of my features are heavely based on ssr stuff. So I had to make it work for srr mode, but now I know ag-grid-vue is fully available on the client side, so I switched back to mode: ssr and made the following:

**Note: Please do not try to run the snippets since I only used them to share the source I have.**

My agGridDemo.vue

```js
<template>
  <ag-grid-vue
    style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    :columnDefs="columnDefs"
    :rowData="rowData"
  ></ag-grid-vue>
</template>
<script>
import { AgGridVue } from 'ag-grid-vue'

export default {
  name: 'ag-grid-demo',
  data() {
    return {
      columnDefs: null,
      rowData: null
    }
  },
  components: {
    AgGridVue
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.columnDefs = [
      { headerName: 'Make', field: 'make' },
      { headerName: 'Model', field: 'model' },
      { headerName: 'Price', field: 'price' }
    ]

    this.rowData = [
      { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
      { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
      { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 }
    ]
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  @import "~/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
  @import "~/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
</style>
```

Nothing new  here, I guess, just that importing the stylesheets in nuxt.config.js file, made the stylesheets unreachable (at  leat in my case). So I added the < style > tag and import the stylsheets as is specified in the [ag-grid docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-getting-started/)

Here's where magic happened, dynamic imports (as you can see in the video I recomended) avoid to import the component code in the the first load, and import it only when is called, this often useful to optimize page load. So in my first attemp i wrote some this:

```
<template>
  <section>
      <comAgGridDemo v-if="mostrarGrid " ></comAgGridDemo>
  </section>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "nuxt-property-decorator";
// import comAgGridDemo from '~/components/comAgGridDemo.vue'
const comAgGridDemo = () => import('~/components/comAgGridDemo.vue');

@Component({
  components: {
    comAgGridDemo
  }
})
export default class extends Vue {
  mostrarGrid: boolean = false;

  mounted() {
    this.mostrarGrid = true
  }

}
</script>
```

So comAgGridDemo will be rendered only when mostrarGrid is true, then in mounted hook (because mounted is available in client side) I made mostrarGrid = true. And It's done.

I went a little futher because, i was not happy using mounted hook for this matter, so I wrapped the component comAgGridDemo on a < srr > tag, remove the v-if, and ag-grid remained rendered just fine. So the index.vue file ended up like this:

My index.vue

```js
<template>
  <section>
    <no-ssr>
      <comAgGridDemo ></comAgGridDemo>
    </no-ssr>
  </section>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "nuxt-property-decorator";
// import comAgGridDemo from '~/components/comAgGridDemo.vue'
const comAgGridDemo = () => import('~/components/comAgGridDemo.vue');

@Component({
  components: {
    comAgGridDemo
  }
})
export default class extends Vue {

}
</script>
```

And that's it.

Note that if you. If you use, < no-ssr > tag with regular import, ag-grid will fail. If you use dymamic import without < no-ssr > tag, ag-grid will fail. If you use the "v-if way" no need to use < no-ssr > tag.

Something is weird on the ssr using ag-grid. But this is how managed to solve it. If there's a better solution, please advise.

I've made a github repo: https://github.com/warheartvik/nuxt-ag-grid

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, although would likely not cause this error, the component in your template should be kebab case. `<ag-grid-demo/>`. From vue [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Component-name-casing-in-templates-strongly-recommended)

The error you are getting is probably an ssr issue, and although you have specified `ssr: false` in your nuxt.config.js this doesn't always get the point across.

Could you try this:

```js
<template>
  <section class="section">
    Welcome to test page
    <no-ssr>
      <ag-grid-demo></ag-grid-demo>
    </no-ssr>
  </section>
</template>
    
<script>
let AgGridDemo = {}
if (process.browser) {
  AgGridDemo = require('~/components/AgGridDemo')
}
export default {
  components: {
    'ag-grid-demo': AgGridDemo
  }
}
</script>
```

Also, as an aside, the modern way to import plugins in nuxt.config.js is as follows.

```js
plugins: [
  '~/plugins/plugin-ag-grid.client.js'
  //Note the .client.js This is shorthand for the following which you can also use
  src: { '~/plugins/plugin-ag-grid.js', mode: client }
]
```

The use of `ssr: false` will be deprecated in the next major release. See [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins#name-conventional-plugin)

**Edit**

If this is still causing errors you may need to add the plugin to `build-transpile` in nuxt.config.js. Like so:

```js
build: {
  ...
  transpile: [
    '/plugins',
  ],
}
```

This will transpile all your plugins but see how you go. Unfortunately the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#transpile) don't give us a lot about this.

If you can't get that to work the old fashioned approach was to add the component to a whitelist like this:

```js
//nuxt.config.js
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

module.exports = {
  /**
   * All other config code
   */
  build: {
    extend(config, ctx) {
      if (ctx.isServer) {
        config.externals = [
          nodeExternals({
            whitelist: [/^@components\\AgGridDemo.vue/] 
            // or however you regex a windows path
          })
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Andrew! I think this fixed it. I am not getting Syntax Error anymore now, however few other issues are still preventing me to render ag-grid. Looking into this and will mark your answer as correct as soon as I make sure this fixed it!

Comment: I am getting now [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <AgGridDemo>
If I replace back the line where we have is browser with import AgGridDemo from '~/components/AgGridDemo' and save, grid works when the dev auto reload occurs, but If I reload the page manually cntrl+f5 on pc I get again : Missing Stack Frames.

Comment: @Nesha8x8 I've added an edit that might help. You're not using IE11 by any chance are you?

Comment: No, testing in chrome and brave (chromium)

Answer (score 0):

It is because the ag-grid is used to work in spa mode. If you want to work in SSR mode you should isolate the ag-gird page like this:

1. make a file selectiveSSR.js in folder serverMiddleware
2. add this line to your nuxt.confing.js
   serverMiddleware: ['~/serverMiddleware/selectiveSSR.js'],
3. in the file '/serverMiddleware/selectiveSSR.js' put this code:

   export default function(req, res, next) {

   ```
        const paths = ['/hear is the name of the page'] // hear is the name of the page
        // A very simple check
        if (paths.includes(req.originalUrl)) {
          // Will trigger the "traditional SPA mode"
          res.spa = true
        }
        // Don't forget to call next in all cases!
        // Otherwise, your app will be stuck forever :|
        next()
      }
   ```

It works for specific URL as spa mode and the ag-grid can come up in spa mode.

4. now you can put the rest of ag-grid code as it is said in the ag-grid document

https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/getting-started/